# Check if a variable was set from SELECT INTO in MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, select, triggers, select-into

I'm not sure if this is already answered or not, but I couldn't find a good solution.

I have a trigger for my table (`source_table`), where it will populate another table (`target_table`). However, when populating the `target_table`, I need to get a value from another table (`intermediate_table`). But I need to `INSERT INTO` my `target_table` only if the value from `source_table` is available in the `intermediate_table`.

My current trigger looks like this.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_source_table_insert;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_source_table_insert AFTER INSERT
 ON source_table
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    DECLARE my_id INT(11);
    SELECT some_id INTO my_id FROM intermediate_table it WHERE it.some_id = NEW.another_id;
    IF my_id <> NULL THEN -- CONDITION ---
      INSERT INTO `target_table` (`target_id`, `updated_at`)
      VALUES (my_id, NOW())
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE   `updated_at` = NOW();
    END IF;
 END;
$$
```

However, the `CONDITION` doesn't seem to work, even when the `my_id` is valid.

What is the best way to execute the `INSERT` query if the `SELECT` populates `my_id`?

Is using `select FOUND_ROWS();` a good option here?

**NOTE**: I don't want to do the `SELECT` more than once because the tables are very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `NULL` values can be compared either using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.
- Also, I have set the default value of `my_id` to `NULL`, to avoid unintended cases. It is generally a good practice to set default values for the declared variables.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE my_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
SELECT some_id INTO my_id FROM intermediate_table it WHERE it.some_id = NEW.another_id;
IF my_id IS NOT NULL THEN -- CONDITION ---
  INSERT INTO `target_table` (`target_id`, `updated_at`)
  VALUES (my_id, NOW())
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE   `updated_at` = NOW();
END IF;
```

Comment: @PraneethPeiris happy to help :)

Comment: Just accepted your answer, it asked me to wait 10 minutes before accepting (for some reason).